# How to link Fred's Magick Script TextCleaner with XCode Project

Tags: xcode, image-processing, imagemagick, ocr

I decided to rephrase the question. Here is the problem:

I've managed to run textcleaner.exe within my c++ program by calling: 
system("/usr/local/bin/textcleaner g -e normalize -f 25 -o 10 [path to infile] [path to outfile]");

But now I get the error:

**/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 389: convert: command not found**

/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 400: [: : integer expression expected

/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 403: convert: command not found

/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 417: [: : integer expression expected

/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 423: [: : integer expression expected

/usr/local/bin/textcleaner: line 429: convert: command not found

**--- FILE /Users/~/Desktop/kimlik/kimlik1.bmp NOT READABLE OR HAS ZERO SIZE ---**

So what is the problem here? I am giving a correct image with the right path, so I think instead of the last line, the problem lies with the convert command within textcleaner.exe.  How can I call textcleaner.exe and convert.exe at the same time s**o that when running the textcleaner.exe, it knows what command convert is?**

Comment: They are scripts and not .exe files

Comment: So if you use chmod u+x textcleaner on the script you get the executable file. I understand that you can call the exec version within c++ code with system(textcleaner [parameters] inputfile outputfile). But running this gives the error: textcleaner: line 389: convert: command not found. I guess I somehow need to add the convert executable as well but I can't figure out how.

Comment: First: The `convert` utility is not in your environment `PATH`. You'll need to load the shell environment, or use `putenv` to rebuild the `PATH`. Second: The `[` character is a test utility, and can not be used as a literal string. See `man [` to learn more.

Comment: Just to see if I'm understanding this right: Isn't adding the path to convert.exe to my PATH in .bash/profile not enough? Because my PATH includes usr/local/bin, in which the convert.exe resides alongside textcleaner

Comment: My script is a bash Unix shell script (.sh) and not a Windows executable (.exe). To run it on Window, you need a Unix environment such as Windows 10 unix or Cygwin. Also do not confuse the Windows convert with the Imagemagick convert. Much of the script is simply the use of Imagemagick's -lat command.

Comment: Hi! I used the instructions to create an executable from the script with chmod u+x, which I then call in c++ code. I can run the executable on Mac with no problem. The issue is that the script uses convert command of imagemagick which my c++ code cannot access. I'm still trying to work around this issue...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend calling an external script from a C++ application. You'll need to worry about paths, loading shell environments, and external error handling. Not really hard to do, but I feel unnecessary. I would argue that if your developing a C++ solution, than integrate with Magick++ directly. Try the following...

Ensure that you installed ImageMagick with Magick++ support. This is usually enabled by default.

Update Xcode's *Build Settings* to include Magick++ flags.

- Run `Magick++-config --cxxflags` in your terminal. The return values should be copied under "Other C++ Flags" option.
- Run `Magick++-config --libs` in your terminal. The return values should be copied under "Other Linker Flags" option.

Xcode project should now support Magick++ library.

Finally, evaluate the source of Fred's fantastic `textcleaner` script. You should be able to mimic his techniques directly in C++.

For example. The script may generate the following convert command.

```
 convert \( $infile -colorspace gray -type grayscale -contrast-stretch 0 \) \
         \( -clone 0 -colorspace gray -negate -lat ${filtersize}x${filtersize}+${offset}% -contrast-stretch 0 \) \
         -compose copy_opacity -composite -fill "$bgcolor" -opaque none  \
         -sharpen 0x1 \ $outfile
```

Which can be implemented with something like...

```cpp
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    long
        filtersize = 15,
        offest = 5;
    const char
        * bgcolor = "white",
        * infile  = "wizard:",
        * outfile = "output.png";

    InitializeMagick(argv[0]);
    Image alphaImage(infile);
    alphaImage.colorSpaceType(GRAYColorspace);
    alphaImage.type(GrayscaleType);
    alphaImage.contrastStretch(0, QuantumRange);
    Image betaImage(alphaImage);
    betaImage.negate();
    betaImage.adaptiveThreshold(filtersize, filtersize, offest);
    betaImage.contrastStretch(0, QuantumRange);
    alphaImage.composite(betaImage, 0, 0, CopyAlphaCompositeOp);
    alphaImage.fillColor(Color(bgcolor));
    alphaImage.opaque(Color("none"), Color(bgcolor));
    alphaImage.sharpen();
    alphaImage.write(outfile);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: output.png]

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Magick++ library is already linked with my project. I think by source of textcleaner script you mean the convert command  at the end of the script, which I find hard to replicate because it requires a good understanding of every image processing step. (There are a lot of steps). Is it theoretically possible to call an external script from c++ ? I really want to understand why I'm getting the error why I am getting. If I can't overcome this problem though, I will follow your suggestion

Comment: Do you consider the following as the source convert command of textcleaner: convert -respect-parenthesis \( $tmpA1 $rotation $cropping $makegray $enhancing \) \
 \( -clone 0  $setcspace -colorspace gray -negate -lat ${filtersize}x${filtersize}+${offset}% -contrast-stretch 0 $blurring \) \
 -compose copy_opacity -composite -fill "$bgcolor" -opaque none -alpha off \
 $unrotating $sharpening $modulation $adaptiveblurring $trimming $padding \
 "$outfile"